# Add string to active merged cells only once - Excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of various horizontally merged cells (3) with text and I want to add a string before every selected one of them but only once (to a merged cells as one).

I have this code but it adds the string three times - counts every single cell in a merged one:

```
Sub Add2Formula()
' Add text

For Each c In Selection
c.Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Text - " & ActiveCell.Formula
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `select` or `activate` anything in VBA (read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7599798)). Use `c` directly and your problem will be gone. Writing into a cell that is part of a merged cell and not the first cell of the merged area will simply be ignored.

```
Sub Add2Formula()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection
        c.Value = "Text - " & c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```